# Sort Array on on Value Difference

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I Have An Array,for example

```
string[] stArr= new string[5] { "1#3", "19#24", "10#12", "13#18", "20#21" };
```

i want to sort this array on

```
3-1=2;
24-19=5;
12-10=2;
18-13=5;
21-20=1;
```

and the sorting result should be like

```
string[] stArr= new string[5] { "20#21", "1#3", "10#12", "13#18", "20#21" };
```

I have to find the solution for all possible cases.

> 1>length of the array is not fixed(element in the array)
>
> 2>y always greater than x `e.g x#y`
>
> 3> i can not use list

Comment: And what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: okk, let me update my question.

Comment: Do you have problem with sorting in array?

Comment: problem is that i can't use list, and i can't think about how to solve this .

Comment: `Just give me the Idea, Code i'll Manage.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var sorted = stArr.OrderBy(s => s.Split('#')
                                 .Select(n => Int32.Parse(n))
                                 .Reverse()
                                 .Aggregate((first,second) => first - second));
```

For Your Case:

```
stArr = stArr.OrderBy(s => s.Split('#')
                                     .Select(n => Int32.Parse(n))
                                     .Reverse()
                                     .Aggregate((first,second) => first - second)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
string[] stArr = new string[5] { "1#3", "19#24", "10#12", "13#18", "20#21" };
Array.Sort(stArr, new Comparison<string>(compare));

int compare(string z, string t)
{
    var xarr = z.Split('#');
    var yarr = t.Split('#');

    var x1 = int.Parse(xarr[0]);
    var y1 = int.Parse(xarr[1]);
    var x2 = int.Parse(yarr[0]);
    var y2 = int.Parse(yarr[1]);

    return (y1 - x1).CompareTo(y2 - x2);
}
```

Comment: also for onle line you can use this Array.Sort(stArr, new Comparison<string>((z, t) => { return (int.Parse(z.Split('#')[1]) - int.Parse(z.Split('#')[0])).CompareTo(int.Parse(t.Split('#')[1]) - int.Parse(t.Split('#')[0])); }));

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem is identical to solving any other sorting problem where the order is to be specified by your code - you have to write a custom comparison method, and pass it to the built-in sorter.

In your situation, it means writing something like this:

```
private static int FindDiff(string s) {
    // Split the string at #
    // Parse both sides as int
    // return rightSide-leftSide
}
private static int CompareDiff(string a, string b) {
    return FindDiff(a).CompareTo(FindDiff(b));
}
public static void Main() {
    ... // Prepare your array
    string[] stArr = ...
    Array.Sort(stArr, CompareDiff);
}
```

This approach uses [`Array.Sort` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `Comparison<T>` delegate implemented in the `CompareDiff` method. The heart of the solution is the `FindDiff` method, which takes a string, and produces a numeric value which must be used for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following ( using traditional way)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] strArr= new string[5] { "1#3", "19#24", "10#12", "13#18", "20#21" };
        var list = new List<Item>();
        foreach(var item in strArr){
            list.Add(new Item(item));
        }
        strArr = list.OrderBy(t=>t.Sort).Select(t=>t.Value).ToArray();
        foreach(var item in strArr)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

    }   
}

public class Item
{
    public Item(string str)
    {
        var split = str.Split('#');
        A = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
        B = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
    }
    public int A{get; set;}
    public int B{get; set;}

    public int Sort { get { return Math.Abs(B - A);}}

    public string Value { get { return string.Format("{0}#{1}",B,A); }}
}
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vyFJuQ)

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Without LINQ and Lists :) Old School.

```
static void Sort(string [] strArray)
    {            
        try
        {

            string[] order = new string[strArray.Length];
            string[] sortedarray = new string[strArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] values = strArray[i].ToString().Split('#');                    
                int index=int.Parse(values[1].ToString()) - int.Parse(values[0].ToString());
                order[i] = strArray[i].ToString() + "," + index;                    
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < order.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] values2 = order[i].ToString().Split(',');
                if (sortedarray[int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())-1] == null)
                {
                    sortedarray[int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())-1] = values2[0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())) >= sortedarray.Length)
                    {
                        sortedarray[(int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())-1) - 1] = values2[0].ToString();
                    }
                    else if ((int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())) < sortedarray.Length)
                    {
                        sortedarray[(int.Parse(values2[1].ToString())-1) + 1] = values2[0].ToString();
                    }
                }                    
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < sortedarray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sortedarray[i]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```